# Question about leaving a job

Tags: careers, education, leave

Recently I received a job offer from an international company to work for their office in Turkey. The company is preparing my contract and residency so I can start my career there. 
In the same time, I have applied for a PhD program in an university, and if I get accepted I am willing to leave my job to continue my education. I want to know if there will be any problems if I leave my job prior to contract period to continue my education. 
I will be so grateful if you can help me with this issue.

Comment: "Recently I received a job offer" - Did you accept the job offer yet? I.e. did you tell them "yes I want to take it"?

Comment: Off topic as "Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions" - Voting to close.

Comment: The answer is entirely dependent on the legal position; if you sign a (legal) contract, you will be bound by its terms. If it specifies a minimum notice period, then you may have to work that period. Really this is not answerable without becoming a legal discussion, except to say that quitting before you start without warning will burn bridges.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to know if there will be any problems if I leave my job prior
>   to contract period to continue my education.

Either you have accepted the job offer, or led the company to believe you will accept the job offer. And the company is spending time preparing your contract and making preparations for you to go to live and work in Turkey.

At the same time, you are planning to go to school if accepted, leaving this company, and haven't told them your plans.

So clearly, there will be problems with the company. You will leave them in a bind. You will burn all bridges there. Anyone who knows what you did will likely not want to work with you again.

If you eventually sign a contract and quit abruptly, there may be legal problems (depending on local laws and customs). In some locales this could affect your future employability.

And there will be problems with your reputation. People will think you are dishonest at best, and a liar at worst. You will prove to others that you cannot be trusted to follow through on your promises. To me this would be the worst potential problem, since I value my reputation a lot.